# Tkinter scrollbar widget not working properly. Scrolling with arrow keys and mouse wheel works, but not by clicking on the scrollbar itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I created a class, which is a listbox with a scrollbar.

The problem I'm having is that if I click the scrollbar arrows or grab the bar to move it up or down it does not work.

Scrolling with the mousewheel or with the key arrows do work.

I'm not sure what is the problem in my code. I'm attaching it below so you can run it and see it by yourself.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

class App_Menu(tkinter.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


    tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    tkinter.Tk.wm_title(self,'test')

    folder_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'test', command=lambda: Listbox_Window([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14], 'title', 'test'))

    folder_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=5)


class Listbox_Window():


def load_list(self, list1):

    for item in list1:
        self.listbox.insert(tkinter.END, item)
    self.listbox.selection_set(0)

def __init__(self, list1, w_title, instruction):

    self.list_window = tkinter.Tk()
    self.list_window.wm_title(w_title)

    self.list_window.grab_set()

    tkinter.Label(self.list_window, text= instruction, font='Verdana 10 bold').pack(pady=5)
    list_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.list_window)
    list_frame.pack(expand = 'yes', fill='both')

    scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(list_frame)

    self.listbox = tkinter.Listbox(list_frame, width=60, activestyle='dotbox', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    self.listbox.pack(side = 'left', fill='both', expand = 'yes', padx=(10,0), pady=10)
    scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill = 'y',pady = 10, padx=(0,10))


    self.load_list(list1)



app = App_Menu()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't properly configured the scrollbar. You haven't told it what function to call when it is clicked on. Using a scrollbar requires two-way configuration. A scrollbar must be told what widget it scrolls, and a widget needs to be told which scrollbar to keep up to date.

In your case you need to add something like this after you create the listbox:

```
scrollbar.configure(command=self.listbox.yview)
```